# How to set bitmap image lanscape to portrait

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-bitmap

In my case, I have landscape bitmap. Now I want to set this image into portrait mode. Also set background of image. How to set this image into portrait without scratch. Can I add canvas for background and make bitmap?

Comment: Show more description with your try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setRectToRect after setRotate and postTranslate doesn't rotate the image but shows the same image in portrait mode.

```
 Bitmap bmp = decodeFile(new File(created_folder + File.separator + "pic00" + (k + 1) + ".jpg"));
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         float scale = 1024/bmp.getWidth();
        float xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = (720 - bmp.getHeight() * scale)/2.0f;
        RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, bmp.getWidth()-100,
                bmp.getHeight()-100);

        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                bmp.getHeight());

            matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            matrix.setRotate(90, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            matrix.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
            matrix.preScale(scale, scale);
```

For further details explore the android developer documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html